Set a default printer in a React so that the user isn't prompted to select a printer and can print directly from the app?
i tried this only npm install react-to-print and created a ComponentToPrint for a div to print and on click of a button to print this div. when i click on print it propmts for a printer to select each time , i am looking for a solution it where i set the default printer for it and it should not ask in propmt, it should directly print that div when we click on print button
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

const ComponentToPrint = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref}>
    <h1>This is the content to print</h1>
    <p>Print this specific div content.</p>
  </div>
));

export default ComponentToPrint;

import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';
import ComponentToPrint from './ComponentToPrint';

const App = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef();

  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print this out!</button>
      <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;


All this does in the end, is call the browser print dialog. You can not pre-select any specific printer in there, from a website context.

This sort of control from Browsers JS is not possible, -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print#changing-print-settings-in-the-print-dialog
